# Docusgin API Embedded Sending

Tags: docusignapi

I created an embedded sender's view but I would like to hide the To and Message fields and buttons and also the documents button that appears on the right.

Also, I would like to hide the footer part where the Send, Go Back and Preview buttons appear.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do this through the API or in the console.

Comment: Can i at least hide or lock the documents button so that they are not able to change documents?

Comment: Do you want them to be able to add tags and edit the recipients?

Comment: Add tags but not edit anything else, i already locked the recipients and subject buttons but I do not seem to find a way to lock the documents button.

Comment: You could do this by using express send, but that would not allow senders to edit the tags either.

Comment: So, i guess the documents button is not lockable right?

Also, I am trying to modify recipients using the xml version and my xmlbody looks like:
                "<signers  xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<signer>" +
                "<recipientId>" + recipient.recipientID + "</recipientId>" +
                "<email>" + recipient.recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                "<name>" + recipient.recipientName + "</name>" +
                "</signer>" +

                "</signers>";

But I get a bad request error, so what am I doing wrong?